# Setdefaultlanguage in polyglossia affects font for numbers

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, math-fonts

I'm trying to use different fonts for text and math, but I want digits in normal text to use the glyphs from the math font. I use LuaLatex and get the following strange behaviour.

The first MWE gives me the result I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% \setdefaultlanguage{norsk}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Constantia}
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
1234567890 $1234567890$
\end{document}
```

[image: ok numbers]

However, I need `\setdefaultlanguage{norsk}`, but then this happens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{norsk}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Constantia}
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
1234567890 $1234567890$
\end{document}
```

[image: not ok numbers]

What's going on?

Comment: The main font you get is not Costantia, but Utopia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, the text font is Utopia everywhere. Here's a proof: I don't use Constantia, which I don't have, but Futura that's pretty distinguishable from Utopia.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

%\setdefaultlanguage{norsk}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Futura}
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

1234567890 $1234567890$ abcdef

\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's not possible to get just the numbers in text in a different font, unless playing tricks with combo fonts in LuaLaTeX, which I wouldn't dare to try.

Why the difference when the language is enabled? Look:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{norsk}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Futura}
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

1234567890 $1234567890$ abcdef

\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, `polyglossia` selects the “Norsk font” at begin document, which happens to be the one defined via `\setmainfont`.

If you just want the math to use `mathdesign`, you have to load it before `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Futura}
%\setdefaultlanguage{norsk}

\begin{document}

1234567890 $1234567890$ abcdef

\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

This will produce the same output with or without the `\setdefaultlanguage` line.

Comment: One should load mathdesign before fontspec, it sets the font encoding to T1. It is more or less luck that the language command resets it to the correct TU.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It would be better if `mathdesign` could be split in the text and math parts.

Comment: yes but not so easy: text and math font setup aren't independant. People want that they "match" (the reason why fontspec (as a "text font" package) affects math too) and so text fonts should be mapped to \mathrm and \mathsf, fonts should be scaled, numbers and other symbols should be take from the text font etc.